How exactly do compilers convert AST to assembly instructions
I am more or less confused on how exactly a compiler converts an AST into machine code. My assumption is some compilers traverse the tree and replace each node with a corresponding assembly instruction. Im attempting to write small compiler but I still need to get more information on how this part is exactly done.
I am writing an arithmetic compiler and my intuition is to create an AST, map every node to an assembly instruction then finally write to a file. The assembly will later be handled by an assembler like gcc
for example
// code representation 
int a = 1+2;

// AST representation
     =
    / \
  int  +
   |  / \
   a  1  2


# final assembly after traversing the tree
# Allocate space for variable 'a'
ALLOC a, 4       # Assuming 'int' is 4 bytes

# Evaluate the expression '1 + 2'
LOAD r1, 1       # Load constant 1 into register r1
LOAD r2, 2       # Load constant 2 into register r2
ADD r3, r1, r2   # Add values in registers r1 and r2, store result in r3

# Store the result in variable 'a'
STORE a, r3

I understand that what I described could be inefficient. However transforming an AST to an IR language is even more confusing.
Thanks!

Depth-first  recursive traversal. Visit the L and R children, then the node itself. If a node is a variable or constant, output a LOAD for it. If it is an operator, output the instruction for the operator. If it’s an assignment, output a STORE instruction.

NB There is no [tag:interpreter] here. You asked about code generation.

@Dai Please buzz off.

"Basic" code generation (straight from an AST) is relatively well covered by introductory compiler textbooks IMO (as is converting to an IR for that matter), although there are a couple of competing techniques to choose from. If you had a more specific question I might have answered it.

Your question effectively asks us to summarise half of compiler construction to you.  That's a bit of a tall order.  Perhaps get a book on the subject or attend a lecture?

A-normalization

Not that this really matters, but my AST would omit/remove the INT part, being handled separately as a declaration, leaving the a=1+2 for code generation.
The simplest approach is to assume an underlying stack machine (later make optimizations and other adjustments for register machine).  Recursively call the code genrator on operands, expect that they have done the right things, then generate for the current AST node.
For a=1+2 in the simplest we would start at =, then evaluate the lhs (left hand side) for address, then evaluate the rhs (right hand side) for value, then indirect store.
So, the generated code wold be something like pushaddr a, push 1, push 2, add, istore.
You can see that lhs needs to be evaluated differently than rhs, so that is a parameter passed to the evaluator/code generator.  Thus, a[i]=b[j] generates an address for a[i] and a value for b[j], then istore..
Getting more sophisticated, we would also offer a side-effect only option beyond lhs/rhs, so a+b; would generate no actual code, for example.
Further, we can delay generation of code for a= by asking for address or variable.  With that, we would delay code gen of pushaddr a, and instead return a value to the caller (=) of "variable a".  The resuling code is sequence would then be push 1, push 2, add, pop/store a — directly storing into a instead of storing into the address of a.
So, now we're looking at the return value of operand evaluation instead of simply assuming it's on the stack.
Next, we can switch to a register machine and allocate either real or fake registers to be resolved later to real registers.  Instead of assuming that the operands for + are on the stack we look at the values returned by evaluation of 1, 2, and expect they are now in registers (and they tell us which).
We can continue incremental improvements in this manner.
Another evaluation approach, used with if/while, is to evaluate conditional expressions for branch to target.  So, instead of forming a 0/1 result for i < 10, then branching on true/false, we might branch more directly on a comparison of i with 10.
There are lots of little improvements like these we can apply.
